# How to get just the branch name from SVN and print it to a variable by splitting the URL?

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn, cmd

I'm trying to get only the name of an SVN branch in a command prompt and set that to a variable.
I was able to successfully get the URL, but am having trouble setting the value for just the name of the branch.
Unfortunately, the %branch% ends up empty.

If there are other easier ways that is good too.
Caveat: No tools (besides SVN) not installed on Windows 7 by default.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`svn info --show-item url`) DO SET fullUrl=%%F
ECHO %fullUrl%

FOR /F "delims=/" %%F IN (%fullUrl%) DO SET branch=%%F
ECHO %branch%
```

Command Window Output:

```
C:\workspaces\Release_10_1>FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %F IN (`svn info --show-item url`) DO SET fullUrl=%F

C:\workspaces\Release_10_1>SET fullUrl=https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1

C:\workspaces\Release_10_1>ECHO https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1
https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1

C:\workspaces\Release_10_1>FOR /F "delims=/" %F IN (https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1) DO SET branch=%F
The system cannot find the file https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1.

C:\workspaces\Release_10_1>ECHO 
ECHO is on.
```

### Expected Results:

fullUrl=`https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1`
branch=`Release_10_1`

### Actual Results:

fullUrl=`https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1`
branch=``

Comment: If you know it will always be the 6th delimited field then you can use the tokens option with your FOR command.  Also in your FOR command put the fullurl variable in double quotes.

Comment: 99% of the time it will be at a specific location, but there's that 1% that I have to take care of, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FOR %%F IN ("%fullUrl%") DO SET "branch=%%~nxF"
ECHO %branch%
```

Selecting the `Name` and `eXtension` of the "filename" in `%%F` yields that part after the final `/`.

quotes inserted in `set` to ensure trailing spaces are omitted from the value assigned.

Comment: Wow.  Didn't think that would work with the forwarded slashes.

Comment: @Squashman: I only tried it as an afterthought. To start with, I used `%fullurl:/=\%` (op: which replaces each `/` in `fullurl` with `\`) :)

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks! I do have one question, though. What are the double quotes around "branch=%%~nxF" for?

Comment: @ScrappyDev: The character string on the line after the `=` is assigned to the variable. Some editors retain trailing spaces (and sometimes you *want* them to) and *if* there are trailing spaces on the line, then these will be included in the value assigned. Using the quotes in the manner indicated will ensure that those trailing spaces are *not* included. Since spaces are reasonably hard to see, especially at the end of lines, it using the conventional syntax can lead to a lot of head-scratching when the trailing-spaces issue is first encountered.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what i figured, I'm just used to seeing only the value in double quotes. Would this allow a variable that starts w/ and/or contains a space character, too?

Comment: Yes. A standard `set` will allow this too - just the trailing spaces in the value are hard-to-see and actually **using** a variable whose name contains a space requires some gymnastics. Best to keep to conventional names unless you really want to be obscure.

Answer (score 1):

Magoo has the better answer.

All these years this was the code I had been using because I assumed the file system would not understand a path with forward slashes.  This would be used to get the last delimited field when you do not know how many delimited fields there are.

```
@echo off

SET fullUrl=https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1
set turl=%fullUrl%

:branch
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=/" %%G IN ("%tUrl%") DO (
    SET branch=%%G
    SET tUrl=%%H
)
IF NOT "%tUrl%"=="" GOTO branch
echo %fullUrl%
ECHO %branch%
pause
```

Comment: Where is the `%%H` comming from?

Comment: It is one of the FOR variables that is specified by the `tokens=1*` option..  The variable is getting split at the first delimiter.  Everything before the first delimiter gets assigned to %%G by the FOR command and everything after the first delimiter is assigned to %%H.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach without `for`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "fullURL=https://svn/path/branches/releases/Release_10_1"

rem // Preset temporary variable:
set "tempURL=%fullURL%"
:LOOP
rem // Split off everything up to the first `/` from the beginning of the string:
if defined tempURL set "branch=%tempURL:*/=%"
rem // Split string equals former string, so no `/` found, hence branch is found:
if not "%branch%"=="%tempURL%" (
    set "tempURL=%branch%"
    goto :LOOP
)
rem // Return found branch, that is everything after the last `/`:
echo(%branch%

endlocal
exit /B
```